# Monotouch change UIImageView image from another class

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, appdelegate

I'm trying to update an imageview (an outlet from Xcode) from another class, but it didn't work.

**AppDelegate**:

```
public UIImageView imageviewLoanInputTabs 
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    imageviewLoanInputTabs = new UIImageView ();
    return true;
}
```

**The other class**:

```
var imageObjOutraClass = (AppDelegate) UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
imageObjOutraClass.imageviewLoanInputTabs.Image = (UIImage.FromBundle ("image11.png"));
```

Comment: Didnt work? Are you getting error?

Comment: Bad job whoever downvoted this user's first question.

Comment: why you loose time to down voted instead of helping?

Comment: Mohib, thanks for your help. i'm starting in mono touch...No error, but the image didn't change

Answer (score 0):

There's no special trick to manipulating `UIImageView`s. Try the following code:

[image: kittehs]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;

namespace SingleFileSolution
{
    public class ContentView : UIView
    {
        public ContentView Companion { get; set; }
        public UIImage Image { 
            get
            {
                return imageView.Image;
            }
            set 
            {
                imageView.Image = value;
            } 
        }

        private UIImageView imageView;

        public ContentView(UIColor fillColor, UIImage initialImage)
        {
            this.BackgroundColor = fillColor;

            imageView = new UIImageView(new RectangleF(10, 60, initialImage.Size.Width, initialImage.Size.Height));
            imageView.Image = initialImage;
            AddSubview(imageView);

            UIButton swapButton = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            swapButton.SetTitle("Swap Image", UIControlState.Normal);
            swapButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
                if(Companion != null)
                {
                    var tmp = Companion.Image;
                    Companion.Image = this.Image;
                    this.Image = tmp;
                }
            };

            swapButton.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 10, 100, 44);
            AddSubview(swapButton);
        }

    }


    public class SimpleViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public SimpleViewController() : base ()
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            var view1 = new ContentView(UIColor.Blue, UIImage.FromFile("image1.jpg"));
            var view2 = new ContentView(UIColor.Red, UIImage.FromFile("image2.jpg"));

            view1.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height / 2);
            view2.Frame = new RectangleF(0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height / 2, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height / 2);

            view1.Companion = view2;
            view2.Companion = view1;

            var view = new UIView(new RectangleF(new PointF(0, 0), UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size));
            view.AddSubview(view1);
            view.AddSubview(view2);

            this.View = view;
        }
    }

    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public  class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow window;
        SimpleViewController svController;
        UINavigationController navController;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            svController = new SimpleViewController();
            window.RootViewController = svController;

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for you help. My problem is that the imageview is an outlet from Xcode...i need to access the image view from another class..

Comment: OK. So are you sure that the C# designer companion class is being set properly? Open the Assistant Editor in XCode, ctl-drag the imageview below the @interface definition and use the "Insert Outlet or Outlet Connection" to specify the field. Save in XCode, switch back to Xam Studio, wait for the "Updating..." message to disappear, and then open the .designer.cs file to confirm that the field is available. At that point, you should be able to assign to it.